# Mod_rewrite is escaping my query strings!

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have this url:
http://dev.example.com//zina/Artist%20One%20Demo?l=7&img=artist%20pic%20can%20can%20be%20named%20anything.jpg&it=full

And it's being rewritten to this:
http://dev.example.com/?p=Artist%20One%20Demo&option=com_zina&Itemid=82&l=7&img=artist%2520pic%2520can%2520can%2520be%2520named%2520anything.jpg&it=full

Because of this rewrite rule:

RewriteRule ^zina/(.*)$ /?p=$1&option=com_zina&Itemid=82 [L,R,QSA]

Does anyone know why, and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [*NE* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):

```
RewriteRule ^zina/(.*)$ /?p=$1&option=com_zina&Itemid=82 [L,R,QSA,NE]
```